# How to install and use packages through Docker run

Tags: javascript, typescript, docker, package, typeorm

My `Docker-compose.yml` is following.

```
version: '3'

services:
  api-server:
    build: ./api
    links:
      - 'db'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./api:/src
      - ./src/node_modules
    tty: true
    container_name: api-server

  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./db/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    hostname: db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
    volumes:
      - './db:/config'
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    container_name: db
```

My `Dockerfile` in`./api`is following

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /src
COPY . .

RUN rm -rf /src/node_modules
RUN rm -rf /src/package-lock.json

RUN yarn install

CMD yarn start:dev
```

and my `package.json` is following. I guess all the packages following is installed by command.

But When I try

`docker exec -it api-server sh`

and

`/src # typeorm migration:create -n PostRefactoring`

`sh: typeorm: not found`

The `typeorm`package is listed in `package.json` therefore I believed to installed and this command can be available.

My question is

① How can I check this package is certainly installed ?
② How can I fix and how can I use this package ?

If someone has opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "terior-api",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^0.5.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^7.1.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^7.1.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/joi": "^14.3.4",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.12.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "joi": "^17.2.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.25",
    "yarn": "^1.22.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.3",
    "@types/jest": "25.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "3.0.2",
    "eslint": "7.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "jest": "26.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "26.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Comment: run ```npm ls typeorm``` check installed or not

Comment: `npm run[-script]` adds `./node_modules/.bin` to the path, likely you haven't done that where you're trying to run `typeorm` directly.